# Can't find my layer in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop

This happens to me quite often, where a layer will "disappear" off canvas and I spend precious time trying to "drag" it back into view.  Its swimming around in the vast gray expanse somewhere.

The layer is set as visible per the layers window/list.  Is there a faster way to locate where the missing layer is?

Comment: I don't have Photoshop, but I believe there should be a way to center a layer to the canvas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When this happens to me I zoom out, slowly locate the layer in the layers side-panel and then a dotty box around that layer appears, then I drag it back to the correct place. - Try to figure out what combination of events make you lose the layer and work out a different workflow to minimise the hassle.

Comment: Zooming really far out is a pretty straightforward approach, thanks for the tip.  This usually occurs when I duplicate a layer from one document to another.

Answer (score 3):

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>(transform) or Edit > Transform.
This will put a box around the object that is off the page and you should be able to see the box to bring it back into view. In combination with zooming out this should work.

Answer (score 1):

I finally realized this happens when I duplicate a layer from one canvas size to another, where the first canvas is larger in a significant way. The above answers were correct, zooming out works, but I wanted to clarify what the cause is, at least for me. Also helps to pay attention to where on the canvas the layer being duplicated from is located. This way you know which direction to drag from ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I've had this issue too. Check to see if your workspace is in "analysis" (upper right hand corner). That's the workspace I use most often. Good luck!!

Answer (score 0):

I use the "Edit --> Transform" method myself. Have also found out that if doing that doesn't show the bounding box, select "View--> Fit On Screen" to rectify.

Answer (score 0):

I have this same issue in my Adobe Photoshop CC 2015.

I restore the "layer" view by going to "Essentials" at top right hand corner, and "Reset Essentials".

Answer (score -1):

@Banjer, I solve the problem by:

- Creating a new layer above all other layers (to ensure I can see it)
- Selecting an area of that layer with the marquee tool
- Pasting into the selected area

The pasted graphic will appear in the new layer.